# Disk quota exceeded problem

Tags: debian

I am using Debian Squeeze. Suddenly I have started facing a problem that my user is not able to make directories and other such tasks. Running `mkdir abc` gives me

`mkdir: cannot create directory 'abc': Disk quota exceeded`

My hard disk is not full `df -h` results are

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              1.8T   39G  1.8T   3% /
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  7.8G  148K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              243M   31M  200M  14% /boot
```

`uname -a` output that might be needed is

```
Linux server 2.6.32-5-686-bigmem #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:27:25 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

**Note:** If I login as root then everything is fine. This problem is only with a particular user

**Edit**: output of `quota`

```
Disk quotas for user user (uid 1000): none
```

output of `quota -g`

```
Disk quotas for group user (gid 1000): 

Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/disk/by-uuid/26fa7362-fbbf-4a9e-af4d-da6c2744263c
8971324* 1048576 1048576    none   43784       0       0
```

Comment: What about `quota -g` (group quota)? Do you have quotas at all on that filesystem? Does running `quotacheck` help?

Comment: output of `quota -g` added above. I dont know about quotas in my file system. All I know is that I have set unlimited in quota option in webmin for two of the users I am running on my debian. Suddenly this user has started giving me quota problem without any change made by me. Regarding `quotacheck` it is not working, giving me `-sh: quotacheck: not found`

Comment: How to recalculate quota -> http://labs.erweb.it/pub/recalculate_quotas.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The disk isn't full, but the disk space allowed for this user is full. You need to check `quota(1)`, perhaps persuade the suspect to clean up their junk, or in an outburst of kindness increase it with `edquota(8)`.

Comment: Both the commands you asked me to run gave my syntax error. `edquota(8)` gave me `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '8'`

Comment: The `(8)` refers to section 8 (administrative commands) of the Unix manuals.

Comment: What is the command that just works?

Comment: the man command understads the section if given as fisrt argument. Therefore: ``man 8 edquota``

Answer (score 18):

The problem in my case was I had exceeded the number of inodes (file entries) supported by the file system. The command

```
df -i
```

revealed the problem in my VM:

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs      1500000 1500000     0  100% /
```

Deleting some unnecessary small files or increasing the amount of inodes (more complicated) resolves the issue. A command like this can help locate which directories have a lot of files in them (in this case searching underneath /var):

```
find /var -type d -size +256k
```

Comment: I think this command is better: `find / -xdev -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -kn1`. Taken from the following [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117094/29867).

Comment: Wow, apparently that was my problem, and the main responsible seemed to be a cloned git repository with a LOT of files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Debian Squeeze, but I had a similar problem and maybe this could help someone else.  My user account is for a student, so it's significantly lower than if I was running Linux from my home computer, but still... In a program I was running, I had output get written to a file.  I ran into an infinite loop and had to cntrl-C from the program to cancel it.  After this happened, I continued to get the error that my quota was full and couldn't save anything.  Solution: Delete the output file my loop was writing to.  After deleting this and fixing my loop my quota was freed back up again.

Answer (score 1):

`du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h`

use this command in the home directory(e.g. `/usr2`) to check which hidden folders are taking up space.

You can also check if there are package cache. It can be safely removed

Comment: Why don't you just use `du` on the `/usr2` directory directly instead of bothering with a complicated globbing pattern (that you don't explain the need for)?

Comment: This might be helpful https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356280/458332