# List only the count of all files/directories for the directory tree of present directory

Tags: find, directory, solaris, ls

I want to list the number of directories under each subdirectory tree of the present directory.
As there are too many directories, I can't go into individual directories and check.
I would like to produce a report something like the one shown in the following picture:

[image]

The issue is: my server is giving some warning that the maximum limit of creating directories is reached. So I wanted to know which directory in my parent directory has the maximum sub-directories (excluding files),

Comment: A small change: where in the pic it says -dir1 -- 8000 (total count of only dirs including all sub directories,no files)..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are my inodes going?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215813/where-are-my-inodes-going)

Comment: Are you concerned about reaching the inode limit, the path length, or something else?

Comment: All these answers, not even a single explanation of what is doing what. Magic is magic indeed.

Comment: I am getting an error in /var/adm/messages "vxfs: [ID 702911 kern.warning] WARNING: msgcnt 5555 mesg 128: V-2-128: number of links reached vx_maxlink for inode 53685 on filesystem". And on searching about it i found out that it is due to the number of sub-directories in FS reaching a limit 32k.

Comment: I have explained the question with an example image. Can you please check and provide the new command.

Comment: try as root `debugfs -R "ncheck 53685" /dev/disk/by-label/…` e.g. `sudo debugfs -R "ncheck 53685" /dev/disk/by-label/root`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure ksh93 solution:

```
FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
for dir in */; do a=( "$dir"/**/* ); printf "%s\t%s\n" "$dir:" "${#a[*]}"; done
```

Result from `/usr/src`:

```
linux-3.17.7-gentoo/:   561
linux-3.5.7-gentoo/:    517
linux-3.7.10-gentoo/:   505
linux-3.7.9-gentoo/:    513
linux-3.8.13-gentoo/:   551
linux-4.0.5-gentoo/:    1849
```

Comment: this commands seems to be giving total number of files + directories. can you modify it just to give directories(and all the sub-directories under it)

Comment: @MostWanted Just remove double dots glob: `for dir in */; do a=( "$dir"/* ); printf "%s\t%s\n" "$dir:" "${#a[*]}"; done`

Comment: This command didn't give me the right output. Might be it was not checking under all the levels of the sub-directories. I have explained the question with an example image. Can you please check and provide the new command.

Comment: @MostWanted Which shell are you using? This command gives me right answer on `bash` and `zsh`. I don't have `ksh` at hand to check. The glob `**/*` descent into **all** subdirectories recursively so will give you total number of files and directories. You may need to set some option to make `**` work, as `setopt -s globstar` in `bash`.

Comment: my server uses bash..

Comment: @MostWanted so it should work. Have you set `globstar`?

Answer (score 1):

You could find the toplevel directories first, then use a second find, to count the number of files and directories within the toplevel directory:

```
$ for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type d | sort); \
      do echo -n "$dir " && find $dir ! -path . | wc -l ; done
./adir 1151
./anotherdir 140
./623de41e44 280
./examples 154
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this suit your need:

The path `/boot` is used for sample demonstration. Change it to the directory you need.

```
for DIR in $(find /boot/* -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
    printf "%40s: %10d\n" "${DIR}" $(find ${DIR}|wc -l)
done
```

Output:

```
                          /boot/grub:        282
                    /boot/grub/fonts:          2
                  /boot/grub/i386-pc:        272
                   /boot/grub/locale:          4
                    /boot/lost+found:          1
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  find * -print | awk -F/ '{c[$1]++;} END { for (c2 in c) printf "-%s -- %d\n",c2,c[c2] ;} '
```

where

- find from directory above the ones you want to sum up
- awk will count top level dir and file and sum up at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The following little loop will list a count of all files *(excepting symlinks)* in child directories of `.`  which exist on the same filesystem as the child directory.

```sh
for d in ./* ./.[!.]* ./..?*
do  ! [ -h "$d" ]  &&
      cd "$d" 2>&3 || continue
      printf "%s:\t" "$d"
      find .//. -xdev -depth ! -type l |
      grep -c '^\.//\.'
      cd ..
done  3>/dev/null
```