# can i safely remove /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log (/var: 100% used)

Tags: linux, logs, disk, jenkins, var

I am running out of disk space with /var system file and noticed /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log file is occupied 7 GB. Can i safely remove this log file ?

Comment: this solution is helped me to understand the log files priority and function that related to linux. i would like to know from the prospect of jenkins. i mean by deleting this log file can affect the configuration ?

Answer (score 3):

The log file is safe to remove if you take the following steps:

1. Stop Jenkins.
2. Verify that nothing is holding the log file open with `lsof /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` (should print no output and non-zero exit code).
3. Do whatever you want with the log file - remove it, truncate it, overwrite it with a blank file, compress it and archive it, etc.
4. (Optional but recommended) Setup [logrotate](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logrotate) to ensure that the log file doesn't grow to 7 GB again.
5. Start Jenkins.

Step 2 is necessary to ensure that you don't end up with any [orphaned inodes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290116/what-is-an-orphaned-inode).

As far as Jenkins is concerned, it doesn't care if you delete the file as long as you do so when Jenkins is not running.

I would also highly recommend looking through the log file, determining what is causing it to grow so large, and coming up with a strategy for reducing unneeded logfile entries.

Comment: Thanks for this!